# SID and other fields added to user information list?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, security

According to stuff I am reading on the web, when an AD user gets added to SharePoint site the following information will get copied from AD to the user information list:

- Display name
- Login name
- Email Address

I think potentially other fields are populated as well (such as sid). I don't have an environment to test this on at present (trying to resolve) but I was wondering if anybody knew if this is this the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to check is to pull up the UIL directly, `/_catalogs/users/simple.aspx`. Editing this view will show you all the data available.

To answer your question, yes it includes Display Name (Name), Login Name (Account), and Email Address (Work Email) fields. SID is only within the User profile service I believe and not the UIL.

Answer (score 2):

The SID does exist in the UIL, but it is not exposed via the Server OM.